# Maven - Why Does it Keep Redownloading Dependencies?

Tags: maven, nexus

When I add a new Maven dependency that I've never used before, I will do Maven build and see the dependencies being downloaded into my local machine from Nexus.  All is good.

I will then create another project, specify the same dependency with the same version, do a Maven build, and I will *again* see the dependencies being downloaded from Nexus into my local machine.

Why are my dependencies re-downloaded every time?  Aren't these dependencies already installed in my local repository?

Comment: First ensure you use exactly the same dependency -- artifactid, groupid, version. Then, in each of the pom located folder, run mvn:dependency:tree. Then you can see a complete dependencies. If both of them are totally the same, then what you observed "keep downloading" deserves a deeper digging.

Comment: Do your poms have `repository` elements in them?

Comment: Are you using IDE for that? Wich IDE? How is the ide configured related to Maven? Using which settings.xml file?

Answer (score -1):

Maven will NOT download artifacts repeatedly. The only exceptions are if you are deleting your local repository (in ~/.m2/repository by default), you are configuring usage of a different local repository and if a new SNAPSHOT version is available.

Comment: It will not redownload .. it will check potentially if you are changing network setup and remote repository, but it will NOT redownload.